# Mozart/Oz configure issue on mac os x

Tags: oz, mozart

I am trying to build `Mozart/Oz` on `Mac os x Mojave` using the following link:
https://github.com/mozart/mozart
and been getting the following configure error. GNU MP lib not found.

I installed `gmp` using `homebrew` and also tried --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp/lib and --with-gmp=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/ but got the same error. Can anyone please help me resolve this?

```
checking for --with-gmp... yes
checking for gmp.h... -I/Users/rr/Software/mozart/gmp/packages/include
checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp (default)... no
checking for __gmpz_init in -L/Users/rr/Software/mozart/gmp/packages/lib/ -lgmp... no
checking for mpz_init in -lgmp (default)... no
checking for mpz_init in -L/Users/rr/Software/mozart/gmp/packages/lib/ -lgmp... no
checking for mpz_init in -lgmp2 (default)... no
checking for mpz_init in -L/Users/rr/Software/mozart/gmp/packages/lib/ -lgmp2... no

configure: warning: required GNU MP lib not found
configure: error: 
The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (gmp)
version 2 or higher is required
to build the system.  It can be retrieved from:

    ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gmp/

The latest version at this time is 4.1.2 and is available
packaged as the following archive:

    ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gmp/gmp-4.1.2.tar.gz

You may find a mirror archive closer to you by consulting:

    http://www.gnu.org/order/ftp.html

configure: error: /Users/rr/Software/mozart/mozart/platform/emulator/configure failed for emulator
configure: error: /Users/rr/Software/mozart/mozart/platform/configure failed for platform
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1: Install Mozart2

**1.1**: Link: https://mozart.github.io/

**1.2**: `Applications/Mozart2` Should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl00m.png

*Also, I can't embed the image because of my low StackOverflow reputation, sorry about that.*

### 2: Adding aliases for `osc` and `ozemulator`

**2.1**:  Open .bash_profile

```sh
open ~/.bash_profile
```

**2.2**: Add the following to file and save

```sh
alias ozc='/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ozc'
alias ozemulator='/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ozemulator'
alias ozem='/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ozemulator'
alias ozengine='/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ozengine'
alias ozwish='/Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ozwish'
```

### 3: Basic usage

**3.1**: Write code in a `.oz`-file
Example: `circle.oz`

```
functor
import
    System 
    Application(exit:Exit)
define
    proc {Circle R}
        local A C D Pi in
            Pi = 3.14
            A = Pi*R*R
            D = 2.0*R
            C = Pi*D 
            {System.showInfo 
                'A: '    # A # '\n' #
                'D: ' # D # '\n' #
                'C: '  # C
            }
        end
    end
    {Circle 20.0}
    {Exit 0}
end
```

**3.2**: Compile code in `ozc`

```sh
ozc -c circle.oz
```

**3.3**: Run compiled code in `ozemulator`

```sh
ozem circle.ozf # .ozf is a compiled .oz file
```